# Angularjs Can I declare module inside another module?

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs, I want to declare a module1, and add module1 as the dependency of module2 in the same file.

module2.js

```
angular.module("module2", [])
```

module1.js

```
angular.module("module2").module("module1", [])
```

The purpose is that I dont want to update 2 files everytime a new module is added. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

module1.js

```
angular.module("module1", ["module2"])
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Style Guide - Modules](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , add module2 as a dependency to the module 1

```
angular.module("module1", ["module2"])
```

just make sure you load module2 ahead of module1 in the HTML references.

```
 <script src="./module2.js"></script>
 <script src="./moudle1.js"></script>
```

Comment: The module source files can be loaded in any order. The dependencies are resolved when the app bootstraps.

Comment: Agreed! i meant the dependencies of the module2